# How to call this curl API request to get the highest 'likelihood' json field name?

Tags: php, json, rest, curl

I'm trying to use this API from this site [fullcontact](https://www.fullcontact.com/developer/docs/name/) for normalizing a number of possible names into 'likelihood values' for name extraction.

Tried the following code but it can't run `Undefined offset: 2 error: $index_name = $possible_names[$n];`. Moreover, I'm was stuck with the logic of extracting the name. Can someone help? Thanks

```
$possible_names = array("Jimmy Frank", "Wall Street"); // In this case Jimmy Frank should be the output person name

if (count($possible_names) > 1) 
{
     for ($n = 0; $n <= count($possible_names); $n++) 
     {
         $index_name = $possible_names[$n];
         $ch = curl_init();
         curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://api.fullcontact.com/v2/name/normalizer.json?q=$index_name");
         curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
         curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "GET");

         $headers = array();
         $headers[] = "X-Fullcontact-Apikey: APIKEY";
         curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

         $namenormalizer_result = curl_exec($ch);

         if (curl_errno($ch)) {
            echo 'Error:' . curl_error($ch);
         }
         else
         {
            $namejson_result = json_decode($namenormalizer_result, true);
            $namejson_array[] = $namejson_result['likelihood'];
         }
         curl_close ($ch);
     }    
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$possible_names` is an array of size 2. Arrays are indexed from 0 so you need to remove the last index `2` which doesn't exist :

```
for ($n = 0; $n <= count($possible_names) - 1; $n++) {

}
```

or use strict condition :

```
for ($n = 0; $n < count($possible_names); $n++) {

}
```

For the extraction, you can use `$namejson_result->nameDetails->fullName` to extract `fullName` and `$namejson_result->likelihood` for `likelihood` :

```
$namejson_result = json_decode($result);

echo "likelihood for $index_name on " . 
    $namejson_result->nameDetails->fullName . " : " . 
    $namejson_result->likelihood . "\n";
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply oh my bad for the size 2 error but did i write my curl wrongly because when i try var_dump(namejson_result) it return NULL instead a value?

Comment: Is `$namejson_result` not empty ? Also, check the status code with `$status = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);` in case you got 400 or anything else

Comment: yes my $namejson_result is empty with NULL when i var_dump? i added $namejson_result = json_decode($result); $status = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE); echo $status; return int(400); whats wrong it should return 200?

Comment: request is malformed, the issue is URL encoding with `$îndex_name`. Use : `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://api.fullcontact.com/v2/name/normalizer.json?q=" . urlencode($index_name));`